# Internet TV streaming fails after 10 seconds with Omxplayer

Tags: streaming-video, omxplayer

I'm trying to see a internet television broadcast with my pi and omxplayer.
The problem is that it loads the broadcast but after 10 seconds the broadcast will freeze.

If I pause and then play again, the stream plays again for a second and stops. I can do this loop all the time.

I tried to over-clock the Pi, to share memory to `128/128/128`,.. and more stuff, but I don't know what I am doing.

How can I fix this to get a continuous stream from this broadcast?

Here is the the information given by Omxplayer about the broadcast:

> omxplayer -i http://www.tv3.cat/directetv3cat/tv3catpc.m3u8
>
> [mpegts @ 0x1c8a4e0] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5013600 microseconds
>
> [mpegts @ 0x1c8a4e0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Unknown: none ([21][0][0][0] / 0x0015)): unknown codec
>
> Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
>
> [mpegts @ 0x1c8a4e0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
>
> [hls,applehttp @ 0x1c77c00] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5013600 microseconds
>
> [hls,applehttp @ 0x1c77c00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Unknown: none ([21][0][0][0] / 0x0015)): unknown codec
>   Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
>
> [hls,applehttp @ 0x1c77c00] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
>
> Input #0, hls,applehttp, from 'http://www.tv3.cat/directetv3cat/tv3catpc.m3u8':
>
> Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 83168.723867, bitrate: 34 kb/s
>
> Program 0
>
> Metadata:
>
> ```
>  variant_bitrate : 2305400
> ```
>
> Stream #0:0: Unknown: none ([21][0][0][0] / 0x0015)
>
> Metadata:
>
> ```
>  variant_bitrate : 2305400
> ```
>
> Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 720x576
>
> [SAR 16:11 DAR 20:11], 12.50 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
>
> Metadata:
>
> ```
>  variant_bitrate : 2305400
> ```
>
> Stream #0:2: Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp,
>
> 128 kb/s
>
> Metadata:
>
> ```
>  variant_bitrate : 2305400
> ```

Comment: What is your internet connection like. Does this happen on other computers while playing youtube videos or internet tv?

Comment: With my computer I can see the broadcast with no problem. So I think it's not about a bad internet connection.

Comment: Is the Pi connected to LAN. If using WiFi on Models earlier than B+ then use a powered USB hub. It might be reconnecting to access point and dropping the connection.

Comment: I'm using B model, but I don't think Is reconnecting to the access point.

Comment: But I am working in the possibility omxplayer lose some package and when is trying to recover it, omxplayer can't. So when I push pause it dismiss this loosed package and go on with the new ones. But for now is only a theory.